# How to check class indexes and its properties, type etc by SQL in OrientDB?

Tags: sql, database, orientdb

I have created Vertex class and id index with type UNIQUE. Now I want to verify if it is created programmatically in my unit test classes.

As I am connecting to the OrientDB via JDBC, I want to check it with pure SQL.

```
select expand(indexes) from (select expand(classes) 
from metadata:schema) where name = '<class-name>'
```

is not working.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an index exists by checking the list of all the available indexes:

```
select expand(indexes) from metadata:indexmanager
```

Hope it helps

Regads

Comment: Thanks, yes it helped.